# How do I reinstate the little number circle onto the yellow text message envelope icon please?

Tags: sms, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I want to reinstate the little Number Circle that (use to) appear on the yellow text message envelope as its completely disappeared from my Samsung G4, which is annoying!? I receive audible notifications when I receive a text but they are no longer 'tallied' up in a number circle, which I found very useful! How do I reinstate the little number circle onto the yellow text message envelope please?